# Which summons can exist simultaneously?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

If my druid casts "Conjure Woodland Being" and "Summon Raven", both can exist at the same time.  But if my Wizard casts "Find Familiar" and "Summon Scratch (the dog)", the familiar disappears.

Which summons can be cast simultaneously?  Is there any way to tell in-game?

Comment: Multiple cleric summons can also co-exist, just not more than one of the same (unless undead). Druids and clerics are quite similar so I guess the same goes for druids.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spell used to summon Scratch *is* Find Familiar!

[image]

Generally speaking, there are two factors at play here: concentration, and spell uniqueness.

The interactions with Concentration are straightforward -- you can't concentrate on two spells, so two spells that summon creatures and require concentration can never exist simultaneously (at least, not from the same caster!).

This means you can't cast **"Conjure Woodland Being"** multiple times in order to fill the tactical grid with critters.

The other major interaction is Spell Uniqueness -- you can't benefit from the same spell more than once. This is why Scratch disappears -- you've replaced the previous **"Find Familiar: Scratch"** spell with **"Find Familiar: Crab"** (or what have you) -- same as if you cast the spell while your current familiar still exists.

I suppose one final variable is duration -- for instance, **Spiritual Weapon** lasts 10 turns, whereas **Animate Dead** lasts indefinitely (or until a long rest, at least). If the duration is too short, you'll find it harder to get overlapping summons.

Comment: Despite what the wiki says, [Conjure Woodland Being doesn't require Concentration](https://i.imgur.com/ZEu3W8i.png)

Comment: D'oh. That's what I get for relying on 5e _tabletop_ spell definitions. (And not having a druid of my own in BG3). I'm not sure if there's a concentration summon spell, but if there is, I'll update the reference to be more game-accurate (instead of D&D 5e-accurate!).

Answer (score 0):

If you give Scratch's ball to another companion, they can summon him, and then you can cast your Find Familiar, and have both critters at the same time.